# Outlook appointment on Server not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, outlook, appointment

I have created Following function to set Outlook appointment. It's work fine while running in localhost with visual Studio Editor. 
But when I upload publish files on server its not working.

Do I need to set anything in server for Outlook or need to include any additional dll/files?

Any help will be appreciated. Pls let me know, if need more information.

```
public void OutLookReminder(string DateTimeVal)
{
    Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application(); // creates new outlook app
    Outlook.AppointmentItem oAppointment = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem); // creates a new appointment

    oAppointment.Subject = "........Subject"; // set the subject
    oAppointment.Body = "--------Body"; // set the body
    oAppointment.Location = "-------Location"; // set the location
    oAppointment.Start = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTimeVal, "dd/MM/yyyy H:mm",null); // Set the start date 
    oAppointment.End = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTimeVal, "dd/MM/yyyy H:mm", null); // End date 
    oAppointment.ReminderSet = true; // Set the reminder
    oAppointment.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15; // reminder time
    oAppointment.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh; // appointment importance
    oAppointment.BusyStatus = Outlook.OlBusyStatus.olBusy;

    // save the appointment
    oAppointment.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you are running this under a service (such as IIS)? You cannot do that.

Where is the appointment supposed to be created? Current user who is using your code in a browser (then your code needs to run locally in JavaScript)?